# Creating .IPA File from xcode beta

Tags: iphone, ios8, custom-keyboard

I am developing app for custom keyboard, i got following issue during generating .ipa file[image]

Please help to solve this issue, thanks

Comment: during which step does it occur? are you trying to upload to the App Store?